# Prove:$\int_{0}^{\infty} x^9K_0(x)^4\text{d}x =\frac{42777\zeta(3)-51110}{2048}$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, indefinite-integrals, riemann-zeta, bessel-functions

Wolfram Alpha says:
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} xK_0(x)^4\text{d}x
=\frac{7\zeta(3)}{8}
$$
Where $$K_0(x)
=\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x\cosh z}\text{d}z
$$
And I proved it by using Mellin transform.
But I also found(guess):
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\int_{0}^{\infty}x^3K_0(x)^4\text{d}x
=\frac{7\zeta(3)-6}{32} \\
&\int_{0}^{\infty}x^5K_0(x)^4\text{d}x
=\frac{49\zeta(3)-54}{128}\\
&\int_{0}^{\infty}x^7K_0(x)^4\text{d}x
=\frac{1008\zeta(3)-1184}{512}\\
&\int_{0}^{\infty} x^9K_0(x)^4\text{d}x
=\frac{42777\zeta(3)-51110}{2048}
\end{aligned}
$$
How to prove them?The Mellin transform doesn't work on $x^3,x^5,x^7...$.Any help be appreciated.

---

Please see:Hypergeometric Forms for Ising-Class Integrals

Comment: Please show your solution using the Mellin transform in the $xK_0^4$ case as it might be a possible approach to evaluate the generalised integrals, and also provides context for your question.

Comment: The Mellin transform still works for $x^3,x^5,x^7\cdots$, and in general, there exists a fifth order linear recurrence to compute $\int_0^\infty x^{2n+1}K_0(x)^4 dx$.

Comment: Thanks for linking [the paper](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.em/1204928528). Theorem 3.2 gives an explicit closed form for the coefficient of $\zeta(3)$. A closed-form expression for the "constant" term (independent of $\zeta(3)$) remains open. Again, please include more detail (either from your attempt or from the paper) in your question.